# JShint :Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I have this line:

```
$scope.campaingstartDate;
```

And JSHint shows the following message:

```
$scope.campaingstartDate;
^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

I am new to Angular JS and JSHint, so what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: assign some default value like  `$scope.campaingstartDate = ''`

Comment: thanks @SameerK ,its working now!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you code work as expected but you think jshint is too "strict" or miss behave for that line of code, you could use the following comment to ignore the warning from jshint:

```
 $scope.campaingstartDate; // jshint ignore:line
```

Alternatively you could assign a default value as suggested on this page.

```
$scope.campaingstartDate = ''; // add any value as default for your property here
```